# When do you get to roll to disbelieve a Spectral Smoke?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, saving-throw

An NPC archer is about to shoot at a PC who has implanted the [Mesmerist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/mesmerist/) Trick Spectral Smoke and setup the trigger so that the smoke appears if he is to be attacked.

Spectral Smoke says:

> A cloud of smoke pops up around the subject, foiling attacks. The
>   mesmerist can trigger this trick when the subject is targeted by an
>   attack or by a spell that requires an attack roll. A smoke cloud
>   appears in the subject’s square and in a 10-foot radius around it.
>   This cloud lasts for 1 round per mesmerist level. The cloud functions
>   as fog cloud, but is an illusion (figment) effect that can’t be
>   dispersed by wind and can be used underwater. **A creature that
>   interacts with the cloud can attempt a saving throw to disbelieve the
>   effect.** The radius of the cloud increases by 5 feet for every 5 caster
>   levels the mesmerist possesses, to a maximum of 30 feet at 20th level.

Does attempting to a shoot a creature standing in the middle of the illusory cloud of smoke count as "interacting" with the cloud such that the archer gets a saving throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Intrigue on [Illusions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/intrigue/#Illusions), in part, says

> But what does it mean to interact with an illusion?… A creature that spends a move action to carefully study an illusion receives a Will saving throw to disbelieve that illusion, so that is a good benchmark from which to work. Using that as a basis, **interacting generally means spending a move action, standard action, or greater on a character’s part. For example, if there were a major image of an ogre, a character who tried to attack the ogre would receive a saving throw to disbelieve**, as would a character who spent 1 minute attempting a Diplomacy check on the ogre.…

(Emphasis mine.) Thus, generally, if the attacker makes an attack against or into an illusion, the attacker is entitled to make a disbelief saving throw against that illusion.

If the GM has ruled that a creature that's targeted a foe must then attack that foe, then the archer will receive a disbelief saving throw even if he misses the target. If the GM has ruled that a creature that's targeted a foe can change its mind about targeting the foe because the foe did something, then the archer won't receive a disbelief saving throw unless the archer interacts in a different fashion with the illusory effect.